# How to Achieve Rounded Corners on a Container in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm working on a Flutter app and am trying to implement a design that includes containers with rounded corners at the top, as shown in these design images:

[image]

[image]

However, I've encountered a problem when trying to replicate this rounded corner effect in my code. Below is the relevant portion of my Flutter widget tree where I'm attempting to create a container with rounded corners:

**This is my code:**

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BackdropFilter(
      filter: ImageFilter.blur(sigmaX: 2, sigmaY: 2),
      child: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
        body: Center(
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(32.0),
            child: Container(
              height: double.maxFinite,
              width: 600,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Color(0xffF6F6F6),
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                  Radius.circular(20.0),
                ),
              ),
              child: LayoutBuilder(
                builder: (context, constraints) =>
                    Stack(
                      children: [
                        Align(
                          alignment: const Alignment(0, -.400),
                          child: Container(
                              child: Image.asset("lib/img/pomodoro.png",
                                width: 250,
                                height: 250,) //image size
                          ),

                        ),
                        Align(
                          alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                          child: Column(
                            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                            children: [
                              ...List.generate(
                                1,
                                    (index) =>
                                    Container(
                                      child: Row(
                                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                                        children: [
                                          SizedBox(width: 0,),
                                          Image.asset("lib/img/google_logo.png",
                                          width: 60,
                                          height: 60,),
                                          SizedBox(width: 10,),
                                          Center(
                                            child: Text("Continue with Google",
                                            style: TextStyle(
                                              fontSize: 25,
                                              fontStyle: FontStyle.normal,
                                             fontWeight:  FontWeight.bold,

                                            ),),
                                          ),

                                        ],
                                      ),
                                      width: constraints.maxWidth,
                                      height: constraints.maxHeight * .1,
                                      color: index.isEven ?
                                      Color(0xffF3F5F4):
                                      Color(0xffF3F5F4),
                                    ),
                              ),

                              ...List.generate(
                                1,
                                    (index) =>
                                    GestureDetector(
                                        onTap: () {
                                    print("LogIn clicked");
                                    Navigator.pushReplacement(
                                    context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => LogInEnterEmailPassword()));
                                    },
                                      child: Container(
                                        child: Center(child:
                                        Text("Log In",
                                          style: TextStyle(
                                            fontSize: 25,
                                            fontStyle: FontStyle.normal,
                                            fontWeight:  FontWeight.bold,
                                            color: Color(0xffF2F2F2)
                                          ),)),
                                        width: constraints.maxWidth,
                                        height: constraints.maxHeight * .1,
                                        color: index.isEven ?
                                        Color(0xffD94530):
                                        Color(0xffD94530),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                              ),
                              ...List.generate(
                                1,
                                    (index) =>
                                    GestureDetector(
                                    onTap: () {
                                     print("Sign Up clicked");
                                     Navigator.pushReplacement(
                                      context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => SignUpNameEmailPassword()));
                                        },
                                    child: Container(

                                      child: Center(child:
                                      Text("Sign Up",
                                        style: TextStyle(
                                            fontSize: 25,
                                            fontStyle: FontStyle.normal,
                                            fontWeight:  FontWeight.bold,
                                            color: Color(0xffF2F2F2)
                                        ),)),
                                      width: constraints.maxWidth,
                                      height: constraints.maxHeight * .1,
                                      color: index.isEven ?
                                      Color(0xff4994d9):
                                      Color(0xff4994d9),
                                    ),
                              ),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
```

When I tried to replicate this container at another place in my widget tree, I received the following error:

```
 Cannot provide both a color and a decoration To provide both, use
 "decoration: BoxDecoration(color: color).
```

**My Attempts to Solve the Issue:**

- I've tried adjusting the `BorderRadius` and `decoration` properties but seem to be missing something in how they interact or are applied.
- I also looked into similar questions here on Stack Overflow, but either the solutions didn't apply to my case, or I couldn't adapt them successfully. For instance, I found questions about rounded corners, but they didn't deal with issues arising from the combination of `color` and `decoration` properties as mine does.

I'm looking for guidance on how to correctly round the corners of a container in Flutter, specifically when dealing with the `decoration` property and avoiding the error I encountered. Any insights or references to relevant documentation would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Are you using it inside dialog

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things that I noticed

1. You can directly assign widgets inside the column without using a Listview builder.
2. Not sure if your UI has anything that will appear on top of the card if not you can use a Column widget in place of stack
3. Also the height is set at double.infinity.

Now to answer the question, you can wrap the widget that you wish to crop with a `ClipRRect` and give it a borderRadius and it will crop to the required region

```dart
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BackdropFilter(
      filter: ImageFilter.blur(sigmaX: 2, sigmaY: 2),
      child: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
        body: Center(
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(32.0),
            child: ClipRRect( //<---here
               borderRadius :BorderRadius.circular(10),
              child: Container(
                height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
                width: 600,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Color(0xffF6F6F6),
                ),
                child: LayoutBuilder(
                  builder: (context, constraints) =>
                      Stack(
                        children: [
                          Align(
                            alignment: const Alignment(0, -.400),
                            child: Container(
                                child: Image.asset("lib/img/pomodoro.png",
                                  width: 250,
                                  height: 250,) //image size
                            ),

                          ),
                          Align(
                            alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                            child: Column(
                              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                              children: [
                                Container(
                                        child: Row(
                                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                                          children: [
                                            SizedBox(width: 0,),
                                            Image.asset("lib/img/google_logo.png",
                                            width: 60,
                                            height: 60,),
                                            SizedBox(width: 10,),
                                            Center(
                                              child: Text("Continue with Google",
                                              style: TextStyle(
                                                fontSize: 25,
                                                fontStyle: FontStyle.normal,
                                               fontWeight:  FontWeight.bold,

                                              ),),
                                            ),

                                          ],
                                        ),
                                        width: constraints.maxWidth,
                                        height: constraints.maxHeight * .1,
                                        color: Color(0xffF3F5F4),
                                      ),

                                 GestureDetector(
                                          onTap: () {
                                      print("LogIn clicked");
                                      Navigator.pushReplacement(
                                      context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => LogInEnterEmailPassword()));
                                      },
                                        child: Container(
                                          child: Center(child:
                                          Text("Log In",
                                            style: TextStyle(
                                              fontSize: 25,
                                              fontStyle: FontStyle.normal,
                                              fontWeight:  FontWeight.bold,
                                              color: Color(0xffF2F2F2)
                                            ),)),
                                          width: constraints.maxWidth,
                                          height: constraints.maxHeight * .1,
                                          color: Color(0xffD94530),
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                GestureDetector(
                                      onTap: () {
                                       print("Sign Up clicked");
                                       Navigator.pushReplacement(
                                        context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => SignUpNameEmailPassword()));
                                          },
                                      child: Container(

                                        child: Center(child:
                                        Text("Sign Up",
                                          style: TextStyle(
                                              fontSize: 25,
                                              fontStyle: FontStyle.normal,
                                              fontWeight:  FontWeight.bold,
                                              color: Color(0xffF2F2F2)
                                          ),)),
                                        width: constraints.maxWidth,
                                        height: constraints.maxHeight * .1,
                                        color:  Color(0xff4994d9),
                                      ),
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          )
                        ],
                      ),

        
            )}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `clipBehavior: Clip.hardEdge` on top Container. Default clipBehavior is  none.

```dart
return BackdropFilter(
    filter: ImageFilter.blur(sigmaX: 2, sigmaY: 2),
    child: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
        body: Center(
            child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(32.0),
                child: Container(
                    clipBehavior: Clip.hardEdge,//here
```